# Property of nth root

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following result:

"Let $x, y \geq 0$ be non-negative reals, and let $n, m \geq 1$ be positive integers.

If $x > 1$, then $x^{1/k}$ is a decreasing function of $k$."

$x^{1/k}:=sup\{y \in \mathbb{R}: y \geq 0, y^n \leq x\}$.

The book says to prove first that if $x>1$ then $x^{1/n}>1$, which I did prove and next I tried to argue by contradiction but I haven't gotten anywhere so far. So, I would appreciate any hint about how to carry out the proof.

Best regards,

lorenzo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lemma 1. If $x>1$ then $x^{1/n}>1$.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that $x^{1/k}$ is increasing, i.e., $x^{1/k}\le x^{1/(k+1)}$. Dividing by $x^{1/(k+1)}$ (since  $x^{1/(k+1)}\ne0$ by lemma 1), we have $x^{1/(k(k+1))}\le1$. Since $x^{1/k}$ is increasing and $\color{blue}1\le \color{red}{k(k+1)}$, we obtain $x=x^{1/\color{blue}1}\le x^{1/(\color{red}{k(k+1)})}\le1$ (why?), i.e., $x\le1$, a contradiction to the hypothesis $x>1$.